# Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/octet-stream"

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I an getting this error `Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.` on my browser console when trying to run my react/django application. Here's my index.html file;

INDEX.HTML

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>BlogHost</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="{% static 'main.jsx' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried using react-django-templatetags.

```
{% load static %}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>BlogHost</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    {% react_render component='main.jsx' %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Yet, I still get a blank page and an error in my console.

Comment: have you tried running `python manage.py collectstatic`, and are you sure you have correctly setup all your STATIC file settings?

Comment: Thanks, I already resolved the problem. I was using react vite with .jsx files while most of the tutorials I was following were all using the traditional react and .js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution for it. According to vite documentation for [backend integration](https://vitejs.dev/guide/backend-integration.html)

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>BlogHost</title>
    <!-- if development -->
    <script type="module" src="http://localhost:5173/@vite/client"></script>
    <script type="module">
        import RefreshRuntime from 'http://localhost:5173/@react-refresh'
        RefreshRuntime.injectIntoGlobalHook(window)
        window.$RefreshReg$ = () => {}
        window.$RefreshSig$ = () => (type) => type
        window.__vite_plugin_react_preamble_installed__ = true
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="http://localhost:5173/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```