# My Github TypeScript website is not showing because the server responded with a MIME type of "application/octet-stream"

Tags: typescript, github, deployment, mime-types, mime

I am trying to build a website using TypeScript, Vite and Node. My website runs locally but I'm getting the error when trying to open it as a Github hosted page.

The full error:
/src/main.tsx:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

```
index.html in the root
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <!-- <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico" /> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React + TS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>

main.tsx in the /src
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.tsx'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

I checked the roots to the files and I ran tsc and npm run build

I have read other discussions on this topic but nothing seems to help and I don't know what else to do

I do not know what could be wrong, this is my first TypeScript project, please help :(

Comment: did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76513703/failed-to-load-module-script-expected-a-javascript-module-script-but-the-server and this: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/61532 ?